# ArrayList<File>() as a Spinner

Tags: java, android

I have an ArrayList() that I want to display as a Spinner. Problem is, I need to display something other than the File.toString(). I would like to set the Spinner's view text to the file name (formatted), not the full file path returned by File.toString(), so I believe this rules out just using ArrayAdapter? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android SDK docs for [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) recommend the following:

> Override the toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list.

Which means you can still use `ArrayAdapter`, but you would need to create a wrapper object which contains your true File eg `FileFormat` which overwrites `toString()` with your desired format.

```
class FileFormat {
    private File delegate;
    FileFormat (File delegate) {
       this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    public String toString() {
       return formatAllPrettyAndWhatNot (delegate);
    }
};
//then use a ArrayList<FileFormat>(), in your array spinner adapter
```